# RC522 RFID Reader connected to Pi 4b does not want to read my card or tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi4, rfid, mfrc522

I'm at my wits end, I've been trying to connect my RC522 module to my RPI 4b, running Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye). I've been trying to use a loopback test on my SPI and it works, but the code below provided by ChatGPT here doesn't seem to work when I try to send data over SPI using spidev.

Expected output is supposed to be:

```
Received: [0xAA]
Received: [0xAA]
Received: [0xAA]
...
```

Actual output:

```
Received: [0]
Received: [0]
Received: [0]
...
```

The code:

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0, 0)  # Open SPI bus 0, device 0

try:
    while True:
        data = spi.xfer2([0xAA])  # Send 0xAA over SPI
        print("Received:", data)
        time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    spi.close()
```

I've been following the Pi My Life Up tutorial on how to connect the RC522 with a Pi [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/). The reader does not want to read my RFID card and RFID tag at all. I've tried 3 different tags already to no avail.

My SPI is enabled and I can see the "spi_bcm2835" on my pi's lsmod.

Comment: TBH, I think this is a good example why ChatGPT can only help if you know exactly what to ask for. Here's a few questions I have about that code which may be error sources: why use xfer2 instead of xfer (see also https://pypi.org/project/spidev/ )? Why send 0xAA, is this a command for the RFID reader? Have you tried using the SimpleMFRC522 library from the linked tutorial?

Comment: @FlorianEchtler According to ChatGPT:
xfer sends and receives data whereas xfer2 is only sending. In the test script it was meant to send the 0xAA which is just a string to check whether it sends.

Yes I was using the SimpleMFRC522 library originally in the tutorial, which I followed to a T and it couldn't read my RFID card/tag

Comment: Do have a look at https://pypi.org/project/spidev/, where xfer and xfer2 are described - the ChatGPT description is incorrect.

Also, if you send a random character like 0xAA, then there is no way to tell how the RFID reader will react to that, and whether it will actually send a response - you would have to send a sensible command, which is exactly what the library does, for example.

I do think you might rather be facing a hardware problem here, have you double-checked that the wiring is correct? And the example doesn't seem to contain any code to make sure that the reset line is low.